# PyMongo null bytes error on import

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, python-3.6

I'm just trying to import the PyMongo package using Python3 and get the following error:

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
```

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo__init__.py", line 83, in 
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

I've tried updating, reinstalling (with pip), cloning from github etc with no joy.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

UPDATE: Must be a local config issue since pymongo working in virtualenv.

Comment: Which version of PyMongo?

Comment: PyMongo v3.6.1.